# How to reload an object connected in xib

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib, uipickerviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController`  (myViewController) with a XIB file. In this XIB file, I have connected an other object `UIPickerViewController` (myPicker).

When my `UIViewController` is allocated, initialized and pushed as a viewcontroller, the `UIPIckerViewController` displays its instance as it should.

The user can modaly open a settingscontroller from `myViewController` to adjust some settings.

When the settingscontroller is dismissed, myViewController is updated (buttons, text, tableview, etc).

However, myPicker is not Only when the `UIViewController` is initalized and pushed again, myPicker is updated.

Is there any good ways to reload myPicker in myViewController without initializing `UIViewController` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try call [myPicker reloadAllComponents]; in viewWillAppear (for that you should make subclass of UIViewController).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Adding [myPicker reloadAllComponents]; did not work. I am not sure if you meant I should subclass UIViewcontroller in viewWillAppear. To clearify, it is the languagesettings that does not update in the UIPIckerviewController (it updates in myViewController).